# Nested model failing to converge - how to make decisions about random intercept only model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, convergence, reporting

I have two models:

```
modela <- lmer(perception~1+self+actual+(1|id/rid),data=data)
modelb <- lmer(perception~1+self+actual+(1+self+actual|id/rid),data=data)
```

and I'm getting warnings for the second model.

Warning messages:

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
3: Model failed to converge with 2 negative eigenvalues: -1.3e-04 -1.3e+02
```

I'm assuming this is because I have random slopes specified in `modelb` even though I don't have enough df. for estimating the slope.
However, the `anova(modela, modelb)` still runs, and shows that the random slope model is better.

[image: anova table as an image]

I'm wondering how `R` is comparing the models (so what exactly the `summary(modelb)` is showing when it's coming out with the warning), and if it's okay to say that I'm using a random intercept model, without the random slope, because I don't have enough df - although the random slope model seems to improve the model (if that's what the anova is really showing I guess...)

How do people decide and report in a paper that they are choosing to run the random intercept only model?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your model did not appropriately converged means that you cannot trust results from it. Hence, neither the output of the `summary()` of the model nor comparing it with the simper model using `anova()`.

Note that random effects are used to model correlations in the data. Moreover, often you may have a more complex design, e.g., nested or crossed levels of grouping variables, but the actual correlations in the data are too weak to support fitting a model with nested/crossed random effects. Hence, offer we start with a simple model with random intercepts with the outer level, and you build it up from there including each time an additional random effects, and checking with a likelihood ratio test if it improves the fit.

Comment: Thanks! So I should start with the simplest model (random intercept) and once the model doesn't converge, that's a good enough reason to stop adding things right?

Comment: You could also try different optimizers to be sure.